# Handling system calls \ standard library exceptional failures

Tags: c++, error-handling

This question should probably be split in two, since it is about two different languages with two different approaches to error handling. However, in my opinion, it corresponds to both C++ and C, since their roots are pretty much common.

So the question is - how should I handle various errors connected to the overall system status, which are *technically possible*, but if they happen then it means that there is *already* something going (or already gone) terribly awry? By this I mean `malloc()` returning `NULL`, `new` throwing `bad_alloc`, Windows\Linux `socket` functions reporting "no free sockets left in system", thread stack overflowing and stuff like that.

Moreover, should I handle them at all? I know that in an ideal world we must handle all the possible errors, so the end user would see *"System failure: couldn't allocate enough memory"* instead of *"Unhandled exception of type 'bad_alloc'"* and *"System failure: Couldn't create socket"* instead of *"Access denied on 0x00000000"*. In C++ we could put in `int main()` something like this:

```
try {
    Program().Run();
}
catch (std::exception e) {
    std::cout << "System failure: " << e.what() << std::endl;
}
catch (...) {
    std::cout << "Unknown system failure" << std::endl;
}
```

, but for me, it doesn't really matters if my program terminates with *"kablams! memory can't be read"* or if there is some wall of text with clever words about handles that couldn't be acquired.

Just to clarify - I'm not a guy who'd say "naaah, imma feelin too lazy to write this wrapper". If I understand that this kind of error can happen, I usually will try to handle it somehow. I'm also not talking about cases when such things can happen (although rarely) on a daily basis, like in embeded systems where we are strictly limited in memory. And not about trivial things like trying to open non-existant file. I'm talking about your classical Linux\Windows C\C++ programs that were tested in a pretty stable environment and will be launched in such an environment 99% of all time.

What I mean is that some of these things are not only exceptional situations, but are somewhat "beyond exceptions" most of the time. And sometimes, if I suddenly remember that memory *may* not be allocated, or read that some system-specific stuff *may* not complete, I'm just left sitting there scratching my head "Wait what, should I actually consider THIS to happen?.."

Comment: Use defensive programming all the time, Murphy's Law and all that. Log it either to system log or custom log.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a sensible response to the error that lets you handle it and continue in a sane manner - like, " if this huge allocation for a buffer throws a bad_alloc I'll catch it and just use a smaller buffer" - then by all means do so.
If you have no sane recourse then either just let the exception propagate up or report the error return value or whatever and then terminate the application.

If errors can be handled in a sane manner and the program can continue after handling the error, then that is great.
In many cases that's not the case and you are better off crashing early rather than trying to continue with "the world" in a non-sane state.